# OpenCL build->crash with useless error

Tags: build, crash, opencl, nvidia, intel

For a little project I've been trying to build a application using OpenCL in combination with OpenGL using the relative python bindings (pyOpenGL and PyOpenCL). Toe be more precise it's supposed to be a generalized raytracer.

After installing both the OpenCL Intel SDK *and* the NVIDIA CUDA toolkit and using the IDE by intel to write the program I've encountered a problem:

Whenever I try to *build* the program either the intel compiler "stopped working" or the NVIDIA one gives me a "invalid value - " message. If I however only *compile* the program everything goes well and nothing bad happens.

If I deliberately place a mistake into the code, both compilers return proper compiler errors with line numbers and all that.

I was able to narrow down the problem to the `__kernal` function but I really can't understand why it wouldn't build but still compile? Is there something I'm missing?

(please excuse the probably bad opencl code. First time I'm writing in anything similar to C)

The Kernal:

```
__kernel void raytrace(__write_only image2d_t renderTexture,
                       int2 pos, __constant float projectionsMatrix[16],
                       //Mesh Data
                       __constant int* meshIndecies, __constant float3* meshVertices,
                       __constant float3* meshNormals, __constant float2* meshUV,
                       __constant int* meshTriangleIndecies, __constant int* meshTriangles,
                       //Material Data
                       __constant float4* emissions, __constant float4* ambients,
                       __constant float4* diffuses, __constant float4* speculars,
                       __constant float* shininesses,
                       //Object Data
                       __constant float* matricies, __constant int* meshes,
                       __constant int* materials) {

    Mesh* meshData;
    int pcMeshv = 0;
    int pcMesht = 0;
    for (int cMesh = 0; cMesh < sizeof(meshIndecies)/sizeof(int); cMesh++) {
        Mesh data;

        //assign data
        for (int index = 0; index < meshIndecies[cMesh] - pcMeshv; index++) {
            data.vertices[index] = meshVertices[pcMeshv + index];
            data.normals[index] = meshNormals[pcMeshv + index];
            data.uv[index] = meshUV[pcMeshv + index];
        }

        pcMeshv = meshIndecies[cMesh];
        for (int index = 0; index < meshTriangleIndecies[cMesh] - pcMesht; index++) {
            data.triangles[index] = meshTriangles[pcMesht + index];
        }
        pcMesht = meshTriangleIndecies[cMesh];

        //add data to array
        meshData[cMesh] = data;
    }

    Material* materialData;
    for (int index = 0; index < sizeof(shininesses)/sizeof(float); index++) {
        Material data;
        data.emission = emissions[index];
        data.ambient = ambients[index];
        data.diffuse = diffuses[index];
        data.specular = speculars[index];
        data.shininess = shininesses[index];
        materialData[index] = data;
    }

    Object* objectData;
    for (int index = 0; index < sizeof(meshes)/sizeof(int); index++) {
        Object data;
        data.mesh = &meshData[meshes[index]];
        data.material = &materialData[materials[index]];

        for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
            data.matrix[i] = matricies[index*16 + i];
        }

        objectData[index] = data;
    }

    //begin trace
    trace(renderTexture, pos, projectionsMatrix,
          objectData, 0);
}
```

The Structs:

```
typedef struct {
    float3* vertices;
    float3* normals;
    float2* uv;
    uint* triangles;
} Mesh;

typedef struct {
    float shininess;
    float4 specular;
    float4 emission;
    float4 ambient;
    float4 diffuse;
} Material;

typedef struct {
    Mesh* mesh;
    Material* material;
    float matrix[16];
} Object;

typedef struct {
    __constant float4 ambient;
    __constant float4 specular;
    __constant float4 diffuse;
    __constant float4 position;

    __constant float3 spotDirection;
    __constant float spotExponent;
    __constant float spotCutoff;

    __constant float constantAttenuation;
    __constant float linearAttenuation;
    __constant float quadraticAttenuation;
} Light;

typedef struct {
    float3 origin;
    float3 direction;
} Ray;

typedef struct {
    float3 point;
    float3 normal;
    float3 bary;
    float dist;
    uint triangle_index;
    Object* object;
} RaycastHit;
```

Thanks for you help,
Benproductions1

Comment: First of all you probably have way too many __constant arguments. __constant memory is meant to be used for small amount of data. The spec mandates that all devices must support at minimum of 8 different arguments with combined size of 64kB and over. Anything more is device dependent. You should use __global const <datatype> * restrict <pointer name> instead. I'd also like to know what you mean by compiling the kernel versus building it? OpenCL 1.1 doesn't really have any concept for that. You can just build a program and that's it.

Comment: I was unable to edit my post anymore. I'll just have to point out that you are probably using OpenCL 1.2 specific features (separate compile and link stages) which are not supported by NVidia. They support only OpenCL 1.1. If you want for your program to be usable on their platform you have to stay on OpenCL 1.1. If you want the situation to change complain to them. They have the capability of supporting OpenCL 1.2 but refuse to do it for strategic reasons.

Comment: I agree with sharpneli. You are even defining the structs as ´__constant´. Remove all the constants all over the code. Only use them when you need really need them. ANother problem you may have is the amount of arguments. The compilers use to crash if you set up too many. Try to group your input somehow in structs.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I've already re-written most of the code now using a different approach, however that still doesn't explain why the compiler crashes on build, or why it gives me a weird error message: "Invalid Value - "...